# Is there a way to keep object members from serializing .NET nulls as "null" in my JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, serialization

I am using WebMethods to return an array of a custom class.  When returning the array from a Jquery .ajax call, it is serialized into a JSON object for use with Javascript in my ASP.NET app.  What I am encountering is that, if any of the members of the Sale class are null (Nothing), it is serialized as a string of "null" in the JSON object.  I really want it to just display an empty string.  I am aware that I can write a clean-up method to turn nulls into empty strings, but I'd really like to know of a way to set a default behavior for this so that nulls are just turned into empty strings.

Here's how all my code looks:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetData(ByVal SaleType As String) As Sale()

    Return DataLayer.GetSalesByType(SaleType)

End Function

Class Sale

    Public Property Type as String

    Public Property InvoiceNumber as Staing

End Class
```

Comment: converting a null value to a "null" string is the wanted behaviour, because there are many aspects where the difference between null and "" is important.

Answer (score 0):

Surely an

```
If x Is Nothing Then # String.IsNullOrEmpty(x) Then
    Return ""
End If
Return x
```

Solves this?

Comment: From my question: `I am aware that I can write a clean-up method to turn nulls into empty strings`.